# python function's arguments with default values get cached for list but not for other types

Tags: python

Below code works the way it does because list "b" is cached at definition time and reused, unless the calling point passes a specific value which initializes a new list for that one particular call.

```
>>> def app(a,b=[]):
...     if a==1:
...         b.append(a)
...    print b
... 
>>> app(1)
[1]
>>> app(1)
[1, 1]
>>> app(1)
[1, 1, 1]
```

But the same behavior does not apply for an argument that's not of type list why?

```
>>> def stri(a,b=""):
...    b=b+a
...    return b
... 
>>> stri("a")
'a'
>>> stri("a")
'a'
>>> stri("a")
'a'

>>> def app(a,b=0):
...   if a==1:
...     b=a+b
...   print b
... 
>>> app(1)
1
>>> app(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because strings are immutable (cannot be changed in place), whereas lists aren't. You are appending to the default argument in the first case, and modifying what the variable points to in the second.

To illustrate:

```
>>> def app(a, b=[]):
...     b = b + [a]
...     print(b)
...
>>> app(0)
[0]
>>> app(1)
[1]
>>> app(2)
[2]
>>>
```

(note that `+=` actually also changes the `list` inplace, so it is semantically different from assignment)

If you want a new `list` for each call, do this:

```
def f(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = []
    ...
```

Or this:

```
def f(a=None):
    a = a or []
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes i understand/knew the way to not get lists cached. but was wondering why int/str behave in un-cached way.

yup, immutability could be the reason why strings and integers get reinitialized each time. 
I tried the same thing on dict and it was caching.. as dict is an mutable type. 

`>>> def addDict(key,value,defDict={1:2,2:3}):
...    defDict[key]=value
...    print(defDict)
...
>>> addDict(8,9)
{8: 9, 1: 2, 2: 3}
>>> addDict(11,12,{1:2})
{1: 2, 11: 12}`

Comment: @SandeepNagaraja I would not refer to this behaviour as "caching"; in all cases, there is only one instance of a default argument, initialised when the function is defined. It's just that you can modify mutable objects, so this change actually shows up in other calls to the function. Immutable objects do *not* get reinitialised - you can check that with proper use of `getattr` and `id`.